# Sulphur Smell in house when dishwasher is unloaded

Tags: dishwasher, smell, sewer

I'm going crazy.  I have had a sulphur/sewer smell going through A/C vents for 6 weeks.  As soon as I smell it, I turn air off for a while ... then it's OK.  IT ONLY HAPPENS 1 TIME A DAY.  I've had A/C people, plumbers.  No one can find anything.  The last 4 days we're figuring when I load/unload dishwasher, that's when smell happens.  No smell in sink or dishwasher.  What could cause this???

Comment: Hello and welcome to Home Improvement DIY. Please take the [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour). Please also specify in detail everything that the plumber looked at, b/c if their nose can't find it, it's going to be hard to hunt down over the internet. For starters, post pictures of the bottom inside of your dishwasher, and the plumbing under your sink.

Comment: I think the problem is in the vent, I guess you shall first check the air vent on the roof for potential blockage.

Comment: Do you have a water softener? If so is it in regen when running the dishwasher?